# Mistake in page number of Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am trying to enumerate in roman my table of contents, and set the counter for arabic only for the first chapter. I has three pages, so I guess this is messing things up. These are some packages I have at the beginning:

Here is all I have related to formating:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\begin{document}
(....) title page, abstract I use \thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage  (...)
```

for the glossary:

```
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{Glossary of Acronyms}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\chapter{Introduction}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

My problem is: table of contents is numbered with 1,2,3 and I want it to be roman numbers, but continue the right counting on the glossary page.

Comment: unrelated but report does not  have a `11.9pt` option

Comment: With only some code snippets instead of a minimal working example, I just would speculate, that you don't want `\addcontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}` (at least) *after* `\tableofcontents`, but `\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman}` *before* `\tableofcontents`. BTW: `\setcounter{page}{1}` before `\pagenumbering{…}` does not make sense.

Comment: this is clearly wrong!! I need help fixing this

Comment: I did what you said, the TOC now has roman, but the glossary starts at i:

Comment: I see no glossary in your code. As already told in my previous comment: Please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Otherwise I cannot help more than already done.

Comment: I edited the question!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but after your edit, the code you show is even farer away from being a minimal working example. What we need is a compilable block of code (as short as possible) that we can copy and paste into our editors and which shows the problems you are facing. At least, this would help us help you identify the reason for the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what exactly you want to do, but as far as I understand, you want the page numbering in your table of contents to be roman (i, ii, iii, ...), but for the other pages arabic (1, 2, 3, ...) and starting again from one. This can be easily achieved using the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents 

\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Now, you mention some kind of glossary in the comments, which, however, is not shown in your code. In order to help you with that, we need more information about how you create this glossary.